# Error encountered while changing case of the letter

Tags: python

I couldn't lowercase this desired line.I don't know what's the problem with this line?

```
"name1".lower()

print(name1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving the lowercased string to a new variable. Try:

```
name1 = "name1".lower()
print(name1)
```

Comment: Now the compiler is printing name1 instead of printing value of the variable(name1) i, i assigned

Comment: @UzumakiPanda remove the quotation marks around name1. so the line would be `name1.lower()`, if your variable name is `name1`.

Comment: Thanks, now I got this ,it's running.

Comment: @UzumakiPanda would you mind clicking the checkmark next to my name to mark it as the correct answer? Thanks.